# Falla una función "if" y un input no acepta el atributo "max"

Tags: javascript, html, css

La primera parte del html explica la función deseada pero lo que falla, en resumen, es que en la función "last stand", el "if" de "last stand" no funciona (solamente dice vivo o muerto). Puse el js completo porque esa función toma valores de ambas anteriores.
Y capaz más fácil pero totalmente desconcertante para mi, es por qué el input de "golpe" se ríe de mi atributo max=999 y permite cualquier valor.

Desde ya pido disculpas por el código extenso pero es que no puedo saber que parte reducida falla.
Gracias!

```js
function hpCalc() {
    var hp = document.getElementById('hp');
    var armor = document.getElementById('armor');
    var hpTot = parseInt(hp.value) + parseInt(armor.value);
    document.getElementById("hpTot").value = hpTot;
}


function moralCalc() {
    var moralIntrinseca = document.getElementById('moralIntrinseca');
    var moralMod = document.getElementById('moralMod');
    var b = parseInt(moralIntrinseca.value) * (1 + (parseInt(moralMod.value) * 0.2));
    b = b.toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById("moralFinal").value = b;
    }


function lastStand() {
        var hpRestante = document.getElementById('hpTot');
        var moral = document.getElementById('moralFinal');
        var golpe = document.getElementById('golpe');
        if (parseInt(golpe.value) >= parseInt(hpRestante.value) && parseInt(hpRestante.value) * parseInt(moral.value)/100 <= parseInt(hpRestante.value) - parseInt(golpe.value)){
            document.getElementById('lastStand').value = "Entra en last stand";
        } else if(parseInt(golpe.value) >= parseInt(hpRestante.value) && parseInt(hpRestante.value) * parseInt(moral.value)/100 > parseInt(hpRestante.value) - parseInt(golpe.value)){
           document.getElementById('lastStand').value = "Muerto";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('lastStand').value = "Vive";
   }}
```

```css
*{
    font: 1em sans-serif;
}

h2{
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

input{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#hp, #armor{
    width: 130px;
}

#moralIntrinseca{
    width: 103px;
}
#hpTot, #moralFinal{
    display: none;
}

#moralMod{
    width: 40px;
}

#golpe{
    width: 103px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculo Last Stand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Last Stand: si HP restante x 1% de la moral es mayor a la diferencia entre el golpe y HP restante. Ejemplo. Axie 100hp Moral 50 recibe un golpe por 120. -> 100 x 0.5= 50 → 120-100=20. -> 50 mayor a 20. -> Last stand</p>
<div class="form-container"></div>
<h2>Stats del Axie Defensor</h2>
<label for="hp">Vida Restante</label><input type="number" id="hp" class="hp" oninput="hpCalc()" placeholder="Vida">
<label for="armor">Armadura</label><input type="number" id="armor" class="armor" oninput="hpCalc()"placeholder="Armadura"><br>
<input type="number" id="hpTot" name="hpTot">
<label for="moralIntrinseca">Moral Intrínseca</label><input type="number" id="moralIntrinseca" class="moralIntrinseca" placeholder="Moral" oninput="moralCalc()">
<label for="moralMod">Buff(+)/Debuff(-) de Moral</label><input type="number" id="moralMod" class="moralMod" value="0" oninput="moralCalc()"><br>
<input type="number" id="moralFinal" name="moralFinal" placeholder="Moral Total del Axie" >
<h2>Stats del Axie Atacante</h2>
<label for="golpe">Daño del Golpe Letal</label><input type="number" id="golpe" name="golpe" placeholder="Daño Letal" max="999" oninput="lastStand()"><br>

<div class="resultado">
    <h2>Resultado</h2>
    <label for="lastStand">Last Stand</label><input type="text" id="lastStand" name="lastStand" readonly></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pongo tu estructura de if resumida para que se vea bien:

Nota: En tu función `lastStand` ajustaría mejor el nombre de tus variables, queda raro que la `hpTotal` que calculas luego sea `hpRestante`.

```
if (golpe >= hpRestante) && (hpRestante * (moral/100) <= hpRestante - golpe)
   "Entras en last stand"
else if (golpe >= hpRestante) && (hpRestante * (moral/100) > hpRestante - golpe)
   "Muerto"
else 
   "Vivo"
```

Nunca va a ser posible que se cumpla tu primera rama Kup, por la tercera expresión que siempre va a ser negativa. Es imposible dado cualquier valor de Vida, que esta sea inferior al golpe, y que además se cumpla que la vida multiplicado por un valor llamado moral divido por 100 sea menor que (la vida - el golpe) que ya tenía que cumplir que fuera mayor que la vida en la primera condición. Te pongo un caso:

```
if (100 >= 50) && (50*0,5*100) <= 50 - 100
```

Como te comentaba, si te fijas la tercera expresión siempre ha de ser negativa, ya que en la primera estás diciendo que `golpe >= hpRestante` luego la resta de `hpRestante - golpe` es un valor negativo que nunca puede ser mayor que un valor positivo que estás devolviendo en la expresión (`hpRestante * moral/100`).

La segunda rama también la podría como `golpe - hpRestante`.

Deberías de modificar esa rama y dejarla de la siguiente forma, para que la tercera expresión sea al menos positiva:

Ahora

Caso 1: `golpe`: 100, `hpRestante`: 50, `moral`: 5 -> Entra en la primera rama 1
Caso 2: `golpe`: 180, `hpRestante`: 150, `moral`: 30 -> Entra en la rama 2
Caso 3: `golpe`: 50, `hpRestante`: 150, `moral`: 40 -> Entra en la rama `else` ya que el golpe no es mayor que el hpRestante

```
if (golpe >= hpRestante) && (hpRestante * (moral/100) <= golpe - hpRestante)
   "Entras en last stand"

else if (golpe >= hpRestante) && (hpRestante * (moral/100) > golpe - hpRestante)
   "Muerto"

else 
   "Vivo"
```

Jejeje me he sentido un poco calculando la vida de un keko de New World!!

Comment: Geniooooooo! Los signos al final están al revés, o sea q primero se moría y luego entraba en Last Stand, pero corregido eso, la estructura lógica fue perfecta! Y si, para practicar, que mejor que con jueguitos y cosas que me den ganas de calcular jajaja

Comment: Qué va! Resolver este tipo de problemas siempre motiva, sobre todo como bien dices, tocamos algo que nos gusta, la suma de aficiones siempre aporta algo positivo. Me alegro que te haya servido. Saludos!