# El min y el max de un input no funciona

Tags: html

Un input al cual le puse los atributos min y max permite cualquier valor. Nunca necesité más que html para eso (soy muy amateur) y no logro entender por qué esta vez no funciona de la manera directa.

Por las dudas, y no se si tiene algo que ver, sumo también la función, en js.

```js
function lastStand() {
    var hpRestante = document.getElementById('hpTot');
    var moral = document.getElementById('moralFinal');
    var golpe = document.getElementById('golpe');

    if (parseInt(golpe.value) >= parseInt(hpRestante.value) &&
            parseInt(hpRestante.value) * parseInt(moral.value)/100 >= parseInt(golpe.value) - parseInt(hpRestante.value)) {
        document.getElementById('lastStand').value = "Entra en last stand";
    } else if (parseInt(golpe.value) >= parseInt(hpRestante.value) &&
            parseInt(hpRestante.value) * parseInt(moral.value)/100 < parseInt(golpe.value) - parseInt(hpRestante.value)){
        document.getElementById('lastStand').value = "Muerto";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('lastStand').value = "Vive";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="golpe" name="golpe" placeholder="Daño Letal" min="1" max="9999" oninput="lastStand()">
```

El código es mucho más extenso y lo tengo completo en la pregunta [Código completo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/490021/falla-una-funci%C3%B3n-if-y-un-input-no-acepta-el-atributo-max), pero me pareció que sumarlo acá sería ser, además de reiterativo, exagerado.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuál es el comportamiento que esperas?

Comment: Q respete ese min y max como valor de entrada? O sea, si pongo 0 no lo tome, o 10000 que no m deje poner el último 0? No se como marca el error el input.